# angular how to handle event inside ng-content

Tags: angular

I'm working on a simple stepper

but I'm stuck on how to handle an event within

ng-content. I've tried with a directive with no luck.

I'd like using appStepperNext and appStepperBack to

handle the click event to navigate within the different steps

I put it in the StepComponent but I'd like to handle it in

the StepperComponent

**stepper**

```
    import {
      AfterContentInit,
      Component,
      ContentChildren,
      QueryList
    } from '@angular/core';

    import { StepComponent } from './step/step.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-stepper',
      template: `
        <ul class="stepper">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index; let last = last">
            <li (click)="selectStep(step)">
              <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" [disabled]="!step.active">
                {{ i + 1 }}
              </button>
            </li>

            <li class="line" *ngIf="!last"></li>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.scss']
    })
    export class StepperComponent implements AfterContentInit {
      @ContentChildren(StepComponent) steps: QueryList<StepComponent>;

      // contentChildren are set
      ngAfterContentInit() {
        // get all active steps
        const activeSteps = this.steps.filter(step => step.active);

        // if there is no active step set, activate the first
        if (activeSteps.length === 0) {
          this.selectStep(this.steps.first);
        }
      }

      selectStep(step: StepComponent) {
        // deactivate all steps
        this.steps.toArray().forEach(step => {
          step.active = false;
        });

        // activate the step the user has clicked on.
        step.active = true;
      }
    }
```

**step**

```
    import {
      AfterContentInit,
      Component,
      ContentChildren,
      Input,
      QueryList
    } from '@angular/core';

    import { StepperNextDirective } from './stepper-next.directive';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-step',
      template: `
        <div [hidden]="!active">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./step.component.scss']
    })
    export class StepComponent implements AfterContentInit {
      @Input() active = false;
      @ContentChildren(StepperNextDirective) dirs: QueryList<StepperNextDirective>;
      ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.dirs);
      }
    }
```

**Dir**

```
    import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[stepperNext]'
    })
    export class StepperNextDirective {

      constructor() { }

    }
```

**Usage**

```
    <app-stepper>
      <app-step>
        Step 1 Content
        <button appStepperNext>Next</button>
      </app-step>
      <app-step>
        Step 2 Content
        <button appStepperBack>Back</button>
        <button appStepperNext>Next</button>
      </app-step>
      <app-step>
        Step 3 Content
        <button appStepperNext>Back</button>
        <button mat-button>Submit</button>
      </app-step>
    </app-stepper>
```

UPDATE after reply of @Bunyamin Coskuner

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Attribute } from '@angular/core';

import { IwdfStepperComponent } from './stepper.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[iwdfStepperNext]'
})
export class StepperNextDirective {
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.stepper.next(this.current);
  }
  constructor(
    @Attribute('current') public current: number,
    private stepper: IwdfStepperComponent
  ) {}
}
```

Next

Comment: The selector in your directive is `iwdfStepperNext` but in your html you have `appStepperNext`. Could that be it?

Comment: Thanks to spot it but it is a simple type. I dont really know how to manage the click button in the step component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the same component for myself and achieved the exact thing you are trying to do.

Here is how you can do it.

You need to define some events within button directives and inject `StepperComponent`.
Also, define a `next` method within `StepperComponent`.

Also, make sure you don't have a typo within your templates. I've changed selector to `[appStepperNext]`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appStepperNext]'
})
export class StepperNextDirective {

  constructor(private _stepper: StepperComponent) { }

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    this._stepper.next();
  }

}
```